# Evaluate an array inside an ES6 map to actually print elements on console

Tags: javascript, console.log, es6-map

### Description

I have an ES6 map. It has a string key, whose value is an array of maps.

The following minimal reproducible code best describes it -

```js
var rootMap = new Map()
rootMap.set('details', [])

var subMap = new Map()
subMap.set('items', ['foo', 'bar'])

// Append subMap to the array in rootMap
rootMap.get('details').push(subMap)

console.log(rootMap)
```

#### The problem

Upon running the snippet, I see this in the terminal -

```
Map(1) { 'details' => [ Map(1) { 'items' => [Array] } ] }
```

I need to get the array values **`foo`** and **`bar`** show up on the console, instead of **[Array]**.

**EDIT:** I can of course log the values by accessing indexes, but this question is really asking to know if it is possible to (literally) replace `[Array]` with the value `['foo', 'bar']`.

#### What I've tried

On searching for existing issues, I tried two things without success -

- using `.fill()` on the array (I thought it evaluates the array, but it doesn't)
- I tried using `JSON.stringify`, but sadly it does not support ES6 Maps yet.

I guess this has to do with JavaScript's style of lazy-loading values in the console.

I need to **print the elements** instead of `[Array]` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

No. it is not possible, because `console` is not configurable.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I can of course access the array values! I believe the question needs an edit about what is being asked.